# The Picard group of an Elliptic Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves, algebraic-groups

Let $(E,O)$ be an elliptic curve. Let $\operatorname{Pic}^0(E)$ stand for the divisors that have degree $0$ where :
$$D = \sum_{p\in E}n_p(P) \text{ and } \deg D = \sum_{p\in E}n_p.$$

I understand that the $\operatorname{Pic}^0(E)$ subgroup of the Picard group is isomorphic to the geometric group on the Elliptic curve. Is it true that the entire Picard group satisfies:
$$\operatorname{Pic}(E) \cong \Bbb Z\oplus \operatorname{Pic}^0(E)?$$
I think the map should be something like:
$$[D] \to (\deg D, [D] - (\deg D) [O])$$ where $[D]$ denotes the divisor class.

This is definitely a group homomorphism onto the first factor, however I don't believe it is one onto the second factor. Is it possible to modify the map/image somehow to get an isomorphism?

Comment: Why do you believe it is not a group homomorphism onto the second factor ? Have you try to compute the image of $[D+D']$ ? By definition, for any curve $C$, there is an exact sequence $$0\rightarrow\operatorname{Pic}^0(C)\rightarrow\operatorname{Pic}(C)\overset{deg}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}.$$ If there is a rational point, the last map is onto and give a splitting of the short exact sequence. This is exactly what you have done with the rational point $[O]$.

Comment: Of course. I was just being dumb...